# Find max value in each row of data table

Tags: c#, .net

I have table like below

```
Date     City    Apple-FT Banana-FT Potato-VG Carrot-VG
03/07    A         25      30       70         65
04/07    B         15      07       15         25
```

I need to get max price in fruits and veg in each day

my code

```
for (int jcol = 1; jcol < dtRep.Columns.Count; jcol++)
{
    DataColumn col = dtRep.Columns[jcol];
    String[] colarr = col.ToString().Split('-');
    String St = colarr[0].Replace(" ", "");
    if (St.Substring(St.Length - 2, 2) == "FT")
    {
        for (int nrow = 1; nrow < dtRep.Rows.Count; nrow++)
        {                                  
             DataRow row1 = dtRep.Rows[nrow];
             object[] array1 = row1.ItemArray;
             decimal maxVal = array1.Select(item => Convert.ToDecimal(item.ToString())).Max();
             for (int i = 1; i < dtRep.Columns.Count; i++)
             {
                 decimal cellValue = Convert.ToDecimal(row1[i].ToString());
                 if (cellValue == maxVal)
                 {
                     // Customize the cell background color for the maximum value here
                     // Example: Changing the cell background color to red
                     row1[i] = "<span style='background-color: red;'>" + cellValue + "</span>";
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: input string is not in correct formatt

Comment: Which is the input string?

Comment: decimal maxVal = array1.Select(item => Convert.ToDecimal(item.ToString())).Max();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. At least an error here:

```
    String[] colarr = col.ToString().Split('-'); // "Apple-FT" --> { "Apple", "FT" }
    String St = colarr[0].Replace(" ", ""); // colarr[0] is "Apple"
    if (St.Substring(St.Length - 2, 2) == "FT") // you need colarr[1] not St
```

You can use 'if (col.ToString()[^2..^0] == "FT")' instead all of above.

2. Then

```
decimal maxVal = array1.Select(item => Convert.ToDecimal(item.ToString())).Max()
```

-->

```
double maxVal = array1.Max(item => Convert.ToDouble(item.ToString()));
```

3. Check in debug what falls into 'object[] array1 = row1.ItemArray;' This can mean 'array1[0] = row1.ItemArray' depending of the type of 'row1.ItemArray'. For sure use:

```
object[] array1 = Array.ConvertAll(row1.ItemArray, i => (object)i);
```

or

```
string[] array1 = Array.ConvertAll(row1.ItemArray, i => (string)i);
decimal maxVal = array1.Max(item => Convert.ToDouble(item));
```

4. It seems array1 may contain the hole row including the date not only selected ("FT") kind. In this case first you need to research the header and list column numbers with desired kind, second you need to take only enlisted columns from array1.

Finally you need something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class Solution {
    static void Main() {
        var hdr = new string[] { "Date", "City", "Apple-FT", "Banana-FT", "Potato-VG", "Carrot-VG" };
        var row = new string[] { "03/07", "A", "25", "30", "70", "65" };
        int l = hdr.Length;
        var ft = new List<int>();
        var vg = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 2; i < l; i++) { // skip first and second columns
            if (hdr[i][^2..^0] == "FT") ft.Add(i);
            if (hdr[i][^2..^0] == "VG") vg.Add(i);
        }
        // for (int nrow = 1; nrow < dtRep.Rows.Count; nrow++)
        // a single row in demo
        double maxftp = 0;
        double maxvgp = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i < l; i++) { // skip first and second columns
            if (ft.Contains(i)) { double d = Convert.ToDouble(row[i]); if (d > maxftp) maxftp = d; }
            if (vg.Contains(i)) { double d = Convert.ToDouble(row[i]); if (d > maxvgp) maxvgp = d; }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("FT {0}, VG {1}", maxftp, maxvgp); // FT 30, VG 70
    }
}
```